# NPM package import causes ERROR in ./node_modules ... export X (imported as X) was not found in Y (possible exports: default)

Tags: reactjs, npm, import

After installing the `wix-style-react` package from NPM to my react app using `npm i wix-style-react`, the moment I import anything from this package my app fails to compile with thousands of errors such as:

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/wix-style-react/dist/es/src/SkeletonRectangle/SkeletonRectangle.js 43:19-21
export 'st' (imported as 'st') was not found in './SkeletonRectangle.st.css' (possible exports: default)
```

(such errors exist for all routes under `./node_modules/wix-style-react/dist/es/src/`)

How can I fix this?
The package obviously should work as it has thousands of weekly downloads, so I'm guessing that fixing this involves some config / import change on my end.

To clarify - this is an external package so I have no control over the exports.

Thanks for your help!

package.json:

```
{
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^14.4.3",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^3.0.4",
    "wix-style-react": "^10.65.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Show hiw you import things